# Bullets disappear for swiper image carousel and only appear when on click for modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, sass

Hello everyone so im having a little bit of trouble with the Swiper for my Image Carousel where they disappear and only appear when I open the modal and close it

So this is the modal, as you can see I used the swiper inside the modal and outside because I have two image carousels one when the modal opens and one when its not open but the problem is the bullets for navigation under the image carousel outside the modal disappear until I open the modal so I think its because it might be connecting with the one in modal but I'm not sure why since I gave them different places In the jquery

```
<div class="modal fade bd-example-modal-lg modalBlur carousel_modal" id="imagemodal" tabindex="-1"
                    role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">

                    <div class="modal-dialog">
                        <div class="carousel-content">
                            <div class="modal-body">
                                <button type="button" class="close_carousel" data-dismiss="modal"><img class="close_position"
                                                                                                       src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri() ?>/assets/images/letter-x.png"><span
                                            class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
                                <div class="carousel-wrapper carousel_for_modal">

                                    <div class="swiper-button-modal-prev swiper-button prev_icon style">
                                        <span class="dashicons dashicons-arrow-left"></span>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="swiper-container">
                                        <div class="swiper-wrapper">
                                            <div class="swiper-slide">
                                                <div class="slider-inner carousel_image">
                                                    //I get the image through PHP here
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="swiper-pagination pagination_modal"></div>
                                    <div class="swiper-button-modal-next swiper-button next_icon">
                                        <span class="dashicons dashicons-arrow-right"></span>
                                    </div>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>


                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="swiper-pagination swiper-pagination-bullets swiper-pagination-bullets-dynamic"></div>
                <div class="swiper-button-next swiper-button">
                    <span class="dashicons dashicons-arrow-right"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="swiper-button-prev swiper-button">
                    <span class="dashicons dashicons-arrow-left"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
```

It's like this on the jQuery

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $('.image-carousel .carousel-wrapper').each(function (index) {
        var $this = $(this).addClass('wrapper' + index);
        $(this).find('.swiper-container').addClass('swiper-item-' + index);
        $(this).find('.swiper-button-prev, .swiper-button-next, .swiper-pagination').addClass('swiper-item-' + index);

        var imageCarousel = new Swiper('.image-carousel .wrapper' + index + ' .swiper-container' + '.swiper-item-' + index, {
            observer: true,
            observeParents: true,
            slidesPerView: 'auto',
            pagination: {
                el: '.image-carousel .wrapper' + index + ' .swiper-pagination' + '.swiper-item-' + index,
                clickable: true,
                dynamicBullets: true,

            },
            navigation: {
                nextEl: '.image-carousel .wrapper' + index + ' .swiper-button-next' + '.swiper-item-' + index,
                prevEl: '.image-carousel .wrapper' + index + ' .swiper-button-prev' + '.swiper-item-' + index,
            },
            spaceBetween: 20,
            breakpoints: {
                992: {
                    slidesPerView: 2.2
                },
                460: {
                    slidesPerView: 1.1
                }
            },
        });
    });
    $('.pop').on('click', function () {
        $('.image-carousel .carousel_for_modal').each(function (index) {
            var $this = $(this).addClass('wrapper' + index);
            $(this).find('.swiper-container').addClass('swiper-item-' + index);
            $(this).find('.swiper-button-modal-prev, .swiper-button-modal-next, .pagination_modal').addClass('swiper-item-' + index);
            // $('.image_on_modal').attr('src', $(this).find('img').attr('src'));

            var imageCarousel1 = new Swiper('.image-carousel .wrapper' + index + ' .swiper-container' + '.swiper-item-' + index, {
                observer: true,
                observeParents: true,
                slidesPerView: 'auto',
                pagination: {
                    el: '.image-carousel .wrapper' + index + ' .pagination_modal' + '.swiper-item-' + index,
                    clickable: true,
                    dynamicBullets: true,
                },
                navigation: {
                    nextEl: '.image-carousel .wrapper' + index + ' .swiper-button-modal-next' + '.swiper-item-' + index,
                    prevEl: '.image-carousel .wrapper' + index + ' .swiper-button-modal-prev' + '.swiper-item-' + index,
                },
                spaceBetween: 10,
                breakpoints: {
                    992: {
                        slidesPerView: 2.2
                    },
                    768: {
                        slidesPerView: 1.8
                    },
                    460: {
                        slidesPerView: 1.1,
                    },
                    375:{
                        slidesPerView: 1.1,
                        spaceBetween: 30
                    }
                }
            });
        });
        $('#imagemodal').modal('show');
    });
});
```

Might it be because of this class? ".image-carousel"

Comment: Hi, can you create demo code ? So it would be easy to understand where problem might exist.

Comment: I figured the problem was with me naming the function and using the same class which is .image-carousel because the modal and the normal carousel were both inside it so I just made another class and but them in different places and it worked atm I'm a bit uncertain if I should delete this post or answer it for others who might do the same mistake thanks for commenting btw

Comment: @Swati was wondering if you have any idea how I can use the swiperjs I'm using there on the second block of code at the ``` $('.pop').on('click', function () {``` so when I click on the picture it opens the one I clicked I'm currently having problem with that just wondered if you have any idea how I can find its src img for the one I click I tried something else but it wasn't working

Comment: Hi where is `pop` in your code .Also where is image located which you need to get `src` from ?

Comment: @Swati on the jQuery code the second function it starts with ` $('.pop').on('click', function () {` that's the .pop and I call the images from Wordpress with php it has a class of image-resoponsive if you think that's something you can use to get it and a parent class of slider-inner that's on the code up there

Comment: there are many images inside that which one you want ?

Comment: Well the one i click that opens on modal i want that one to show since for now it starts from the first one always

Comment: That code is not there in your provided htmls

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223696/discussion-between-swati-and-anup).